# After Migration the Web server getting Fatal error Interface 'Monolog\ResettableInterface' not found

Tags: magento2

After Migration the Web server, I am getting this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Monolog\ResettableInterface' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 28
```

when running the following command

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably some files is missed when you migrated the Webserver.

Please check and make sure the Following Files exists on below path,

> app/etc/config.php

Comment: ohh, Yes unfortunately that config file is not in above path